# How do I integrate an expression of the form $(x + c)^n dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to integrate:

$ \int \frac{2000}{(x + 100)^3} dx$.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do a $u$-substitution for $x+100$.

Comment: A little TeX question: isn't there a special form for the $dx$ or $dt$ in an integral?

Comment: @BillThomas I know what you are talking about. This isn't exactly it, but you could do \text{d}x to get $\text{d}x$

Comment: @BillThomas some people use `\mathrm{d}x` or, to get slightly better spacing, `\,mathrm{d}x`. This looks like $\int x \,\mathrm d x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u=x+100$. Then $du=dx$. So the original integral becomes $\int \frac{2000}{u^3} du$.  This is equal to $-\frac{1000}{u^2}+C$.  Substituting $u$ back yields $-\frac{1000}{(x+100)^2}+C$.